# Field not exist issue

Tags: odoo

I am using the Odoo 12 Community version. When I navigate to an employee an error shows `ValueError: Field 'ifsc' does not exist` and can't open the employee menu. I have inherited employee and it exists in both view and model.

```
class HrEmployeeInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.employee'

    sno = fields.Integer(string='Serial No.')
    pay = fields.Integer(string='Paycode')
    employee_name = fields.Char(string='Emp Name')
    designation = fields.Char(string="Designation")
    account = fields.Char(string="Account")
    bank = fields.Char(string="Bank")
    doj = fields.Date(string="Date Of Joining")
    ifsc = fields.Char(string="IFSC Code")
    present = fields.Float(string="Present Day")
    m = fields.Char(string="M-L")
    wd = fields.Float(string="WD")
    sat = fields.Integer(string="Saturday/Holiday")
    week = fields.Integer(string="WeekOff")
    leave = fields.Float(string="Leave Adjustment")
    payable = fields.Float(string="Total Payable Days")
    ot = fields.Float(string="Tdays-OT")
    days = fields.Integer(string="T.Days")
    wages = fields.Integer(string="Basic wages")
    curre = fields.Float(string="Current sal")
    sal = fields.Integer(string="% of Salary")
    covid = fields.Float(string="Covid 19 salary")
    pf = fields.Float(string="PF")
    esi = fields.Float(string="Esi")
    pay = fields.Integer(string="Payable")
    adv = fields.Integer(string="Advance")
    tds = fields.Integer(string="Tds")
    netpay = fields.Float(string="Net Payable")
    icici = fields.Float(string="ICICI")
```

I have added `'depends': ['base','hr_contract','hr','hr_payroll']` in depends.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problem and provide some code that you did? @payal mishra

Comment: i have created custom module and inherit employee page.

Comment: Make sure the python file is loaded.